# Is there a way in Google Sheets to order cells in a range in the way depicted in the attached file and with one single formula?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a situacion like this:
[![Cell reorder][1]][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2GZI.png

In column `A:A` I have some keys list, with an associated order (column `B:B`). Then I have some values in column `E:E` associated with the previous keys spread in column `D:D` and with a suborder (column `F:F`).

In column `H:H` I have the desired results; all the values listed, following their suborder, and grouped under the associated key, and everything ordered by the keys order takeb from column `B:B`. Besides that, the keys are prefixed and suffixed with several hypens.
I would like to achieve these results with one single formula located in cell `H2`, or cell `H1` including the header (in the example I am using several `sort` & `filter` formulas).
Down below is the link to the spreadsheet in case you need it. 
The formula should be able to accept as many keys, orders, values and suborders needed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XDaJFE_BYJpkhdq32iPHzucjf78mP2WCrDN76U5KwZM/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce("Header",tocol(sort(A2:A,B2:B,1),1),lambda(a,c,{a;"--- "&c&" ---";choosecols(sort(filter(E:F,D:D=c),2,1),1);if(,,)}))
```

[image]

Comment: I have a further question, if I may. What if there's a value that belongs to two different sets of keys? For instance, Singapore is both a city and a country. I have modified the example Spreadsheet adding a second column next to "keys" (D:D). How this new situation may affect the formula so that in Column K:K I can see Singapore in both the Countries and Cities groups? This situation may be extendable to Values belonging to multiple Keys, not just 2. Thank yo so much.

Comment: Checkout the formula added in `Cell I1`

Comment: magnificent!!! thank you so much. I admit that these solutions totally overwhem me